# iOS <video> preview in Chrome

Tags: html, html5-video, mobile-safari

On an iphone, videos that I'm loading through a  element appear with the immovable iOS play button overlay.

When viewing the site in the Chrome browser, I'm able to see the first frame of each video behind the play button. In Safari for iOS, I only see the play button and the blank video player behind it.

I would like users to see the video preview in both browsers the way they can when using Chrome. How can I achieve this in iOS Safari?